# Search Form Based On Tutorial Not Working

Tags: search

Ive based this on the twenty twelve theme, and copied a tutorial and built the following searchbox:-

```
<header>
    <h1 class="page-title"><?php 
    printf( 
        __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'PCDConsulting' ), 
        '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' 
    ); 
    ?></h1>
</header>


<?php /* Start the Loop */ 
if ( have_posts() )
{
    while ( have_posts() )
    {
        the_post(); 
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); 
    }
}
else
{
?>
    <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'PCDConsulting' ); ?></h1>
        </header>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php 
            _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 
                'PCDConsulting' 
            ); 
            ?></p>
        </div>
    </article>
<?php
}
```

This is also my searchform:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/MilkNHny/search.php">



     <input type="text" name="s" value="Search PCD" onblur="if(this.value == ''){ this.value = 'Search PCD'; this.style.color = '#BBB';}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search PCD'){ this.value = ''; 

     this.style.color = '#000';}" style="color:#BBB;" placeholder="" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />



 </form>
```

Its not actually returning anything, please can someone advise if i have missed something?

www.milknhny.co.uk/SofiaWork

Thanks in advance
Kirsty

***EDIT***

I copied both the search and results from the twentyeleven theme and i cant understand why its still not working :S

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_sidebar('slider'); ?>

<div class="maincontent">


<div class="mctitle"><div class="questiontriangle"></div><?php echo get_the_title(); ?>    </div>   
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<div class="maincontentwrap" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Search Results for: %s', 'PCDConsulting' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></h1>
        </header>



        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>



    <?php else : ?>

        <article id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
            <header class="entry-header">
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'PCDConsulting' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="entry-content">
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords.', 'PCDConsulting' ); ?></p>
                <?php get_search_form(); ?>
            </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        </article><!-- #post-0 -->

    <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
```

Is there something im seriously missing here????

Comment: There is no `if` for your `else :`.

Comment: Hi Toscho, fab thanks for this, where do i insert it? is it <?php if ?

Comment: `/* Start the Loop */ if ( have_posts() ) :` should do it.

Comment: HI Toscho <?php /* Start the Loop */  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> I placed this, and it came up with a santax error?

Comment: Sorry, your code formatting is rather … hard to read. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hi Toscho, I will try "tidy" it up, unfortunately tutorials aint the best

Comment: I tried to reformat your first code block. Always use real brackets, not those clumsy `endif` constructs.

Comment: Hi Toscho, thankyou for this, is there something missing at the end with the php?

Comment: came up with a parse error? Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/milknhny/public_html/SofiaWork/wp-content/themes/MilkNHny/search.php on line 49

Comment: Your HTML for the form is wrong first of all. You can't use two form opening tags. The second one is not needed. Do you have [debug constants](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) on?

Comment: Hi Netfreak, the 2nd one is the actual search box, its not in the actual search.php which is the 1st piece of code?

Comment: The HTML mess-up ain't important at the moment, but you have to turn debugging on and fix the PHP error on your search.php template so we can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Crystal Ball Programming and Why Your Searchbox Failed

Your form fails because of this:

```
action="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/MilkNHny/search.php"
```

You should ***never*** directly call a template via URL.

Your template assume the WordPress environment has been loaded, which is a fair assumption. However, because you called it directly, it has not.

Search.php is the template WordPress looks for when it does a search. It doesnt do the actual search. If we apply some logic, browser goes to search.php, and immediatley tries to display the results without:

- bothering to actually perform the search
- loading plugins and themes
- checking rewrite rules
- sanitising data

Since PHP has no crystal ball functionality, things error out. Sorry if it seems brutal, but the point needed demonstrating effectively.

Remember, a computer does as it's told, not as it's expected. If you can't answer the question *"Why would it do that?" or "how does it know?"* then there's a very, very good chance that it doesn't know, and it doesn't do that, and things are going to blow up spectacularly.

## How a Search Request Works

When you go to a URL, WordPress looks up a big list of regular expressions and sees which is the first one that matches. These 'regexes' tell WordPress how to map `/category/example-category/hello-world` into something it can pass into WP_Query, e.g. `name=hello-world`. The parameters are identical to those used in WP_Query, which is where the post loop comes from.

One of these parameters is ***`s`***. The search form passes in the search query via the URL e.g.:

```
example.com/?s=helloworld
```

WordPress then passes this `s` parameter into its main loop query, and makes a mental note:

> "hey the `s` thing is there, this must be a search query! Does the theme have a search.php? LOAD THE SEARCH.PHP TEMPLATE!!!!!! ( ps: load index.php if we don't )

So now WordPress goes off and somewhere there's a `WP_Query( array ( 's' => 'helloworld' ) )`, and it's all wrapped up so you can then print it out using have_posts etc

## So The Basic Search Form is?

So now that we know how a search query works, lets see the basic markup:

```
<form method="GET" action="<?php echo home_url(); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="s">
</form>
```

- method="GET" because GET variables are passed in the URL, POST variables are passed in headers we don't see in the address bar
- `home_url()` because that's the main index of the site. We could search within a category of a date archive by putting ?s= on the end of other pages, but lets assume we want to search the entire site
- `name="s"` because this is the query var WordPress uses to specify a search string

We can expand this further using other functions such as `get_search_query()` etc, but those aren't necessary.

## A Bonus

You don't need to submit a search string from the frontend either. Say you wanted to add a box that listed posts containing the word "Moomins" ( because everyone loves moomins ).

I could do this by doing a post query with the `s` parameter, e.g.:

```
$q = new WP_Query( 's=Moomins' );
$while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
}
wp_reset_postdata(); // clean up after ourselves
```

And hey presto, a list of titles of posts from a search for "Moomins"

Comment: thanks for this Tom, i am trying to learn unfortunately and failing XD

Comment: Not at all, you're making progress!